# react-native with redux polish characters

Tags: react-native, redux

i'm working on a project in react-native with redux and i faced the following issue:

Variables from redux store doesnt include polish characters such as 'ą', 'ę'. Them work fine through all application, but when passed to redux store 'ą' changes to 'a', 'ę' to 'e' unexpectedly. Did anyone found any solution to this problem?

1. variable in TextInput: `"ąąąą"`
2. variable in console provided by
   react-native-debugger: `"ąąąą"`
3. variable in redux-store (debug also
   provided by react-native-debugger): `'aaaa'`
4. value after extracting it from store: `'aaaa'`

Comment: Please paste code snippets instead of linking to screenshots of code.

Comment: These are screenshots of this variable in TextInput in application, in console provided with react-native-debugger and the variable displayed in redux store, also provided by react-native-debugger. The code is just simple console.log of variable passed later on to store to show that in console it displays gracefully whereas in redux store it's wrong.

Comment: The code snippet would be 
```function saveFullName(guestName) {
    console.log(guestName);
    return {
        type: SAVE_FULL_NAME,
        payload: guestName.trim(),
    };
}```
Not much helpful as i guess.

Comment: I was meaning, paste the text that is in the screenshot. For example variable in redux: `guestName: "Aaa"`. Variable in text: Ąąą... This will mean people do not need to open up 4 tabs just to read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found and issue, it was not related to redux store. [Lodash's](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) function `startCase()` made this behavior.